# Antiderivative Theory Problem

Tags: calculus

A function $f$ is differentiable over its domain and has the following properties:

1. $\displaystyle f(x+y)=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{1-f(x)f(y)}$
2. $\lim_{h \to 0} f(h) = 0$
3. $\lim_{h \to 0} f(h)/h = 1$

i) Show that $f(0)=0$

ii) show that $f'(x)=1+[f(x)]^2$ by using the def of derivatives Show how the above properties are involved.

iii) find $f(x)$ by finding the antiderivative. Use the boundary condition from part (i).

---

So basically I think I found out how to do part 1 because if $x+y=0$ then the top part of the fraction will always have to be zero.

part 2 and 3 are giving me trouble. The definition is the limit $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$

So I can set $x+y=h$ and make the numerator equal to $f(h)$?

Thanks for all who help

Comment: I can't accept 2 answers as the correct one, so i'm going to pick Omnomnomnom as it because I had more trouble with the second part. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is much easier than you're making it.  If $f$ is differentiable, it has to be continuous.  If $f$ is continuous, then $f(0) = \lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$.

For the second question: note that
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = 
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\left(f(x+h) - f(x)\right) = 
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\left(\frac{f(x)+f(h)}{1-f(x)f(h)} - f(x)\right)
$$

Comment: I see but wouldn't the limit of that last part be zero? How would I use that to find the derivative?

Comment: The limit of what part?  I don't understand the question.  The next step should be to put the expression in the parentheses over a common denominator

Comment: Oh I see, so then I can solve for f(x)^2 and plug that into the derivative?

Comment: Why are you solving for anything? All you have to do is evaluate the limit.  If you evaluated properly, you should end up with 
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = 1+[f(x)]^2
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears @Omnomnomnom has most of 2) covered I'll simply note that
$$
f(x) = \frac{f(x) - f^2(x)f(h)}{1-f(x)f(h)}
$$

Now I'll look at 3). In order to solve the ODE:
$$
\frac{df}{dx} = 1 + f^2
$$

We simply separate the parts out to get
$$
\int \frac{df}{1+f^2} = \int dx
$$

Thus
$$
\arctan{f} = x + C \iff f = \tan \left( x + C \right)
$$
Now we see from part a) that $f(0) = 0$ so
$$
0 = \tan(0 + C) \iff C = \arctan{0} = 0
$$

and we get our solution of
$$
f(x) = \tan(x)
$$

Comment: thanks I didn't know how to use the zero involved in part a, but I understand now

Comment: @EagleTamer no problem! I'm glad you found the light!